# Showing $X$, $Y$ are not independent but $\operatorname{Cov}[X, Y] = 0$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, covariance

A pair $(X, Y)$ is a point on a single circle $\{(x, y) \mid x^2 + y^2 \le 1\}$. Place this point in the form It is determined randomly and uniformly distributed.

What I want to show is $X$ and $Y$ are not independent But $\operatorname{Cov}[X, Y] = 0.$

Comment: So you start with the uniform distribution Z on the unit circle? Then you write Z=(X,Y). What do you want to prove? Please imrpove your question!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_uniform_distribution

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are certainly not uniform on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @TonyK why not?

Comment: @Stockfish i did some improvement.

Comment: Because, if I understand your question correctly, $X$ is of the form $\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is uniform on $[0,2\pi)$. Similarly for $Y$.

Comment: Fixed. it was my mistake.

Comment: @lighting There are still some errors in your question statement (after you responded to TonyK). Do you want a uniform distribution over the unit disk (2-dim) or just over the unit circle (1-dim)? From your marginal densities $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ it looks like you want the uniform over the disk. However, your joint (2-dim) density $f_{XY}(x,y)$ makes no sense being $1-x^2 - y^2$.

Comment: @Lee David Chung Lin it's over a unit circle. maybe i should just remove my solution to avoid more mistakes.

Comment: @lighting Then why is there still a smaller sign in your first line? $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ describes the unit disk.

Comment: ِI have no clue about it that was the reason i needed some help to understand it, if it is a unit disk then what should be the joint density?

Comment: This is a somewhat tricky problem and I think you are making progress (+1). Please keep at it. // You have two possibly helpful answers now. Don't give up. // The conditional density on the unit circle is a constant, chosen so that the integral over the unit circle is unity. What would the constant have to be?

Comment: And some of the links in the right-hand margin may also be helpful. [Especially this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445536/continuous-uniform-distribution-over-a-circle-with-radius-r?rq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you would like to consider the approach that doesn't require explicitly writing down the densities (formally it can be done with [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) and [Dirac Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) and is not really very advanced).

The calculation-free approach below is applicable for both uniform over the circle or over the disk.

---

To show $Cov[X,Y] = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]\overset{?}{=}0$, it suffices to notice that

$E[X] = 0$ due to mirror (refection) symmetry with respect to the $y$-axis. Similarly, $E[Y] = 0$ due to symmetry about the $x$-axis.

$E[XY] = 0$ for the following reasons. The product $xy$ has a magnitude that is four-fold symmetric in the four quadrants, while the sign of $xy$ in the four quadrants are alternating: positive in 1st, negative in 2nd, positive in 3rd, and negative in 4th. Whatever the joint density $f_{XY}(x,y)$ looks like, it is also four-fold symmetric and the integral $\int xy\cdot f_{XY}(x,y) dxdy$ is going to have the four parts that cancel exactly.

Thus $Cov[X,Y] = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = 0 - 0 = 0$

---

The fact that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent is simply because that the range (a.k.a the domain, or the support) of $X$ is a function of $Y$ and vice versa. When the the range **depends** on the other one, there's your dependency.

As long as by definition your 2-dim distribution is zero "outside" where $x^2+y^2>1$, the two random variables (the two coordinates) are dependent. This has nothing to do with uniformity or symmetry.

Comment: What do you mean by the integral $∫xy⋅fXY(x,y)dxdy$ is going to have the four parts that cancel exactly?

Comment: Sorry if my wording intended to emphasize something ended up being confusing. The integral over the entire first quadrant equals exactly in magnitude with the integral over the entire 2nd quadrant, only that the signs are opposite. Similarly, the 3rd is going to cancel the 4th. Of course, you can pair up $1$st-with-$4$th and $2$nd-with-$3$rd. What I wanted to emphasize was that the cancellation is clear cut as the 4-fold points $(x,y),\,(x,-y),\,(-x,y),\,(-x,-y)$ and not in some complicated cross region delicate balance.

Comment: It is actually a stronger cancellation: 4-fold-pointwise. However, since we are avoiding directly referring to the 2-dim joint density, I decided to phrase it as "the 4 parts", meaning the 4 quadrants. Does this address your question?

Comment: Yes, i got it now Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use Polar Coordinates, such that $X=R\cos\Theta, Y=R\sin\Theta$.   Due to uniform distribution of $(X,Y)$ over the disc, $\Theta\sim\mathcal{U}[0;2\pi)$ and $R,\Theta$ are independent. Then we have that:

$\begin{split}\mathsf E(X)&=\mathsf E(R\cos\Theta)\\&=\mathsf E(R)~\mathsf E(\cos\Theta)\\\mathsf E(Y)&=\mathsf E(R)~\mathsf E(\sin\Theta)\\ \mathsf E(XY)&=\mathsf E(R^2)~\mathsf E(\cos(\Theta)\sin(\Theta))\\&=\tfrac 12\mathsf E(R^2)~\mathsf E(\sin(2\Theta))\end{split}$

Hint: firstly evaluate the expectations for trig functions of $\Theta$ when $f_\Theta(\theta)=\tfrac 1{2\pi}\mathbf 1_{\theta\in[0;2\pi)}$.

---

Note: If the distribution is over a circle rather than the disc, $R\sim\delta(1)$. Otherwise the same principle applies.

Comment: Why does the uniform distribution imply that $\Theta$ and $R$ are independent/ that $\Theta$ has uniform distribution?

Comment: If the point $\langle X,Y\rangle$ is *uniformly* distributed over the disc, then the distribution *possesses rotational* symmetry. Thus there *cannot* be a bias in the distribution for the arc angle, and the arc angle *cannot* influence the radial distance. @user0

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I guess you are supposed to do. I don't want to work the problem,
but to illustrate ideas. So I'm using simulation as a way to make pictures and
to get approximate results (roughly speaking, usually accurate to 2 places).

Start with $X \sim \mathsf{Unif}(-1,1),$ and independently $X \sim \mathsf{Unif}(-1,1).$ Their joint distribution is uniform on the square with vertices at
$(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1).$

Then condition on the values outside the unit circle. That conditional distribution
is uniform on the unit circle. However, in the conditional distribution $X$ and $Y$ are no longer independent, as you have noted. An easy way to see this is that
$P(X > .75|X^2 + Y^2 \le 1) > 0$ and $P(Y > .75|X^2 + Y^2 \le 1) > 0,$ but
$P(X > .75, Y > .75|X^2 + Y^2 \le 1) = 0,$ *not* 
$P(X > .75|X^2 + Y^2 \le 1) \times P(Y > .75|X^2 + Y^2 \le 1) > 0.$

```
# generate 100,000 points in unit square
set.seed(1016);  m = 10^5
x = runif(m, -1,1);  y = runif(m, -1,1)
circ = (x^2 + y^2 <= 1);  sum(circ)     # points inside unit circle
## 78555                                # fraction of points inside circle
pi/4
## 0.7853982                            # fraction of area inside circle

# conditional distribution on circle
x.c = x[circ]; y.c = y[circ]
plot(x, y, pch=".", col="grey")         # plot all 100,000 points (color grey)
points(x.c, y.c, pch=".", col="blue")   # color those inside circle blue
```

It only takes one example where the product of probabilities is not the probability of the intersection to show independence. A small square
at upper-right (inside the square, outside the circle) provides a convenient case.

```
# focus on small square in upper-right corner
abline(v=.75, col="red");  abline(h=.75, col="red")
mean(x.c > .75); mean(y.c > .75)
##  0.0719114                           # aprx P(X > .75|Circle)
##  0.07126217                          # aprx P(Y > .75|Circle)
mean(x.c > .75)*mean(y.c > .75)
##b 0.005124563                         # aprx product
mean((x.c > .75) & (y.c > .75))
##  0                                   # P(X>.75,Y>.75|Circle) = 0
```

Unconditionally, inside the unit square $X$ and $Y$ are independent so their
population correlation is $\rho = 0$ and the sample correlation of the 100,000
points observed is $r \approx 0.$

By contrast, within the unit circle the conditional distribution of $X$ and $Y$
is *not* independent. We have seen this because of the 0 probability in the small
(red) square. However, within the circle the population correlation is $\rho_c = 0$ and the sample correlation is the 78,555 points inside the circle is $r_c \approx 0.$

```
cor(x,y)
## 8.206786e-05  # aprx 0
cor(x.c,y.c)
## 0.0002690579  # aprx 0
```

[image]

The unconditional bivariate PDF in the square is $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 1/4,$ for
$-1 <x,y<1.$ The conditional PDF in the circle is $f_{X,Y|C}(x,y) = 1/\pi,$
for $x^2 + y^2 < 1.$ To find the conditional correlation, you need to find
the conditional covariance, and that is conveniently found by evaluating
$E(XY|X^2+Y^2<1)=0.$ So you need to integrate over the circle (perhaps one quadrant at a time, so you can see how the pieces cancel to 0 by symmetry).