# Random vector $(X, Y)$ has a uniform distribution on the unit circle.

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Faced with the following problem, I do not understand how to solve this problem:

> Random vector $(X, Y)$ has a uniform distribution on the unit circle. Will its components be independent?

It is not very clear to me how to approach such tasks, is it necessary to look for a vector distribution function here? But it's probably clear that we need to check the definition somehow. $X,Y$ independent $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathbb P(X < x, Y < y) = \mathbb P(X < x) \cdot \mathbb P(Y<y)$ But how to do this is not very clear.

Comment: @lulu It is not very clear why from the fact that $X = 0$ it follows that $y = \pm 1$

Comment: @Michael Yes, that was my question, which I never figured out.

Comment: @lulu Yes, it's right

Comment: @lulu The unit circle is not just the circumference. When $X=0$ the condition for $Y$ is $ 0\leq Y \leq 1$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, because I'm just learning and I don't quite understand how to reason if I have little experience, but it's important for me to solve such problems

Comment: @lulu you can be right, for some reason it seemed more natural to me to include the interior. The problem with independence is the same though.

Comment: @lulu And I'm sorry, I was thinking, but I understand correctly that this is essentially our vector $(X, Y)$ displays $\Omega$ into a single circle. But then if I consider the value of X at some boundary point 1, for example, the Y = 0 and this proves that they are addicted?

Comment: @lulu now I'm a little confused, because in fact we need an area $X^2 + Y^2  \leqslant 1$Then how would there be a contradiction that both X and Y are about 0? But, if one value is near its boundary value, then it seems that something about the second one is definitely clear

Comment: Again: your post shows no effort. That means it's not appropriate for this site.  You see from the comments that some users think you mean disk instead of circle.  Why not clarify that point in your post?

Comment: @lulu Listen, I don't speak English, so I use a translator, it just seems that you don't really understand yourself and because of you I got as much as -3 down, do me a favor, never answer my questions again, thank you!

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2958460/305862) with a validated answer considering both cases (uniform distribution on the disk and/or unif. distrb. on the circle =boundary of the disk).

Comment: @JeanMarie Good link but as far as I can tell they concentrate a lot on correlation being zero while about dependence they simply write "The fact that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent is simply because that the range (a.k.a the domain, or the support) of $X$ is a function of $Y$ and vice versa."

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether we're talking about just the boundary or including the interior of the circle, it is very easy to see that the components are not independent by considering a region between the unit square and the unit circle, e.g. $A = [0.8, 1] \times [0.8, 1]$. Clearly $P(0.8 \leq X \leq 1) > 0$ and $P(0.8 \leq Y \leq 1) > 0$, but $P((X, Y) \in A) = 0$.

Comment: This $A$ is the point $(0.8,1)\,.$ If you meant $P(0.8\le X\le 0.8)$ and $P(1\le Y\le 1)$ then all three probabilities you are considering are zero. If you meant what you wrote then $A$ should be different but then $P((X,Y)\in A)$ is not zero.

Comment: @KurtG. I fixed a typo, I think it's fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
A=\left[-\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}},\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}}\right]\times\left[-\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}},\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}}\right]
$$
be a square of area two that is inscribed in the circle with radius one.

Simple geometric considerations show that the area of each of the four regions that is not covered by the square is
$$
\frac{\pi-2}{4}\,.
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left\{-\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}}<X<\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}},-\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}}<X<\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}}\right\}&=\frac{2}{\pi}\,,&\text{(normalized area of square)}\\[4mm]
\mathbb P\left\{-\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}}<X<\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}}\right\}&=\frac2{\pi}+2\frac{\pi-2}{4\pi}\,,&(\text{square plus two extra regions})\\[4mm]
\mathbb P\left\{-\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}}<Y<\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}}\right\}&=\frac2{\pi}+2\frac{\pi-2}{4\pi}\,.&(\text{ditto})\\[4mm]
\end{align}
It is easy to check that the first probability is not the product of the last two.
Therefore $X,Y$ are dependent.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They are not independent: A mathematical reasoning can be:

$f_{x,y} = \frac{1}{\pi}$ (given)

From here we can find $f_{x} = \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} f_{x,y} \, dy = \frac{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\pi}$

We know, for condition of independence to hold, $f_{x|y} = f_x$ i.e. x and y are independent random variables.

Now, $f_{x|y} = \frac{1}{\text{Area of the square formed when Y=y}}=\frac{1}{2y\sqrt{1-y^2}}$

Since, $f_{x|y} \neq f_x$, therefore **x** and **y** are not **independent** random variables.

If you find any issues in my answer, please do let me know.

Happy to cooperate!